# Why SCSS variable is not changing value on media query?

Tags: css, variables, sass, media-queries

Want to change my variable value on media queries but the value doesn't change at all. Why is that?

I tried to simple change the value on the media query but nothing happens.

```
// My variables
// All these variables works outside the media queries

$marq-width: 80vw; // using this one
$marq-height: 20vh;
$marq-elm-displayed: 5;
$marq-elements: 9;
$marq-elm-width: calc( #{$marq-width} / #{$marq-elm-displayed} );
$marq-animation-duration: calc(#{$marq-elements} * 3s);
$color: black;
$break-md: 600px;


// Here is my problem

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: red; // this works
  }

  $marq-width: 100vw; // this not work

}
```

Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/G-ROS/pen/JjPzovR?editors=0100

You can shrink the viewport on <= 600px and see the background changing to red but the variable did not changes at all. I expect the variable changes has the value "100vw", but it remains with the original value of "80vw".

Comment: This is not how SASS/SCSS works. When it compiles to CSS, it doesn't know there is a media query, it's simply trying to set the **value** of a variable to a _property_. You will need to look into a `mixin`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sass - Changing variable value based on media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372006/sass-changing-variable-value-based-on-media-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to define `width` you define the `variable` but not `width`.

chnaging only `variable` will not impact on `css` you will use that variable to such `css` like below.

```
@media(max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: red; // this works
  }

  $marq-width: 100vw; // this will not work
  .marquee{width:$marq-width;}  // this works

}
```

Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/sumitpatel/pen/yLBwaBR)