# Using properties as variables In CSS Preprocessors?

Tags: css, sass, less

I know that both Sass and Less support the `variable` directive. I'm only familiar with Sass, but is there any syntax allowing to use a property *instead* of a variable?

For example:

```
$height: 1rem;

$line-height: 1.5;

@if($height > $line-height) {
  input {
    //
  }
}
```

This works, obviously, but is there *any* possible way to use `properties` instead of `variables` in *any* CSS preprocessor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variables for CSS properties in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292749/using-variables-for-css-properties-in-sass)

Comment: @MaxiGui, No, but thanks. I'm looking for especially *properties* not variables *compiling* to properties.